# are username and password needed when setting a TCP client connection using sierra wireless modem?

Tags: sockets, tcp, gprs

I am using the following sequence of commands when trying to establish a GPRS connection with
a Sierra Wireless modem:
at+wipcfg=1

at+wipbr=1,6

at+wipbr=2,6,11,"APN name"

at+wipbr=2,6,0,"user name"

at+wipbr=2,6,1,"passwd"

at+wipbr=4,6,0

at+wipcreate=2,1,"ip addr",80

at+wipdata=2,1,1

My problem is that I don't use username or password, because they were 
given to me when I purchased the sim card I am currently using. Do I
need to ask the mobile company for those? or are username and password
fields set on the server side of the communication link? I have tried 
omitting them but I get an error when using at+wipbr=4,6,0, or sometimes
I get just the echo from the modem (no OK, no ERROR).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You said "My problem is that I don't use username or password, because they were given to me when I purchased the sim card I am currently using"  Do you mean they were NOT given to you when you purchased the SIM card?

Answer (score 0):

Username/password in case of GPRS used for Authentication via RADIUS inside operator's network (on GGSN node). It depends on the mobile operator if it should be used or not. This days most of the operators don't care regarding the fields username and password.